# Split string from text file but only use some of it for analysis

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `txt` file with the following in

```
Jordan: your pin is at 1257
Harry: your pin is at 1390
```

How can I use split but then only use the name and pin to print out on screen and ignore the rest of it? E.g

```
For J in file:
    A,b,c,d,d,f,g = J. Split
    Print(a,g)


Jordan 1257
Harry 1390
```

Comment: Is this a single line? "Jordan: your pin is at 1257 Harry: your pin is at 1390"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the name and pin:

```
file = ["Jordan: your pin is at 1257", "Harry: your pin is at 1390"]

for line in file:
    name = line.split()[0]
    pin = line.split()[-1]
    print(name + " " + pin)
```

Output:

```
Jordan: 1257
Harry: 1390
```

If you want to store the name and pin you can use a dictionary:

```
file = ["Jordan: your pin is at 1257", "Harry: your pin is at 1390"]

myDictionary = {}

for line in file:
    name = line.split()[0][:-1]
    pin = line.split()[-1]
    myDictionary[name] = pin
```

Output:

```
>>> for i,j in myDictionary.items():
    print(i + ":" + j)


Jordan: 1257
Harry: 1390
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the pattern throughout the whole text is the same.
If I understand correctly what you want, the following code should do it for you. It replaces the parts that you don't want with spaces and leaves only the name and the pin:

```
>>> input = "Jordan: your pin is at 1257 Harry: your pin is at 1390"
>>> output = input.replace(": your pin is at ", " ")
'Jordan 1257 Harry 1390'
```

You only need to use *split* if you want to create a list, from the the resulting string:

```
>>> output.split()
['Jordan', '1257', 'Harry', '1390']
```